# Make postcss work with jss of material ui

Tags: javascript, material-ui, next.js

I met this problem using material UI: To build my app which runs in some old browsers, css needs to be prefixed, e.g:

```
display:flex;
```

What I want is after packing it should add some compatibility automatically:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

and my css was created this way:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
const styles={
        root:{
              display:flex
          }
    }

export default withStyles(styles)(APP)
```

Anyone knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your postcss by creating a `postcss.config.js` file at the project root and define exports

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-easy-import")({ prefix: "_" }), // keep this first
    require('cssnano')({
      preset: 'default',
    }),
    require("autoprefixer")({
      browsers: [
        '>1%',
        'last 4 versions',
        'Firefox ESR',
        'not ie < 9',
      ]
    })
]};
```

Make sure your `webpack` configuration has a rules for postss:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ["babel-loader", "raw-loader", "postcss-loader"]
},
{
  test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    "babel-loader", "raw-loader", "postcss-loader",
    {
      loader: "sass-loader",
      options: {
        includePaths: ["your/src/scss/style/file/location", "node_modules"]
          .map(d => require('path').join(__dirname, d))
          .map(g => require('glob').sync(g))
          .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope it's works for you.

Comment: I don't see a way for the postcss-loader to be applied here since it is triggered only for css|scss files, but OPs file has `.js` extension.